# YAML library giving two different outputs

Tags: python-3.x, list, yaml

The expected output format is as follows:

```
- start: [45, 78]
- goal: [56, 89]
```

I tried the following code on two different machines:

```
import yaml 

dict_file = [{'start' : [45,78]},
         {'goal' : [56, 89]}]

with open('store_file.yaml', 'w') as file:
   documents = yaml.dump(dict_file, file)
```

Machine with **YAML 3.12** gives:

```
- start: [45, 78]
- goal: [56, 89]
```

Machine with **YAML 6.0** gives:

```
  - start:
    - 45
    - 78
  - goal:
    - 56
    - 89
```

However, I want to get the same output (as in the machine which has YAML 3.12) in the machine which has YAML 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the abbreviated form for the list by setting `default_flow_style` argument to `None`.

```
import yaml

dict_file = [{'start': [45, 78]},
             {'goal': [56, 89]}]

with open('store_file.yaml', 'w') as file:
    documents = yaml.dump(dict_file, file, default_flow_style=None)
```